# Use Powershell and 7zip to put files into seperate .7z by starting letter

Tags: powershell, sorting, 7zip, explorer

I have a script that puts files into folders based on the starting letter (for example, files starting with 'A' go to a folder called "A", starting with 'B', a folder named "B" and so forth.) Heres the code:

```
97..122 | foreach {
    $letter=[char]$_
    New-Item -Path .\ -Name $letter -ItemType "directory"  
    move-item .\$letter`?* $letter
    $list +=  $letter
}

$rest=get-childitem -path .\ -exclude $list 
New-Item -Path .\ -Name "rest" -ItemType "directory"

foreach ($f in $rest) {
    move-item  $f.fullname "rest"
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to do that, but instead of folders, compress them into .7z files with 7zip (preferably with compression on "Ultra")

Answer (score 0):

You would use `Start-Process` to start 7z using -ArgumentList to specify the commands.

https://superuser.com/questions/940878/how-to-pass-multiple-files-to-zip-in-a-single-command-using-7-zip

The 'a' command adds files to the archive.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
'a'..'z' | ForEach-Object {
    7z.exe a -mx9 -o "$OutputFolder" "$_.7z" ".\$_*.*"
}
```

You'll need to consult the 7-Zip documentation to understand the 7z.exe command syntax.